# Class destructor being called twice after initialization

Tags: c++, class, destructor

I have a class:

```
class square
{
    int* _ptr;
public:
    square(int * ptr )
    {
        _ptr = ptr;
        *_ptr = 0;
    }

    ~square()
    {
        delete _ptr;
    }
};
```

I have another class with a `square` member, and I initialize is like this:

```
member = Square::Square(new int);
```

When the new square created by the constructor goes out of scope, the destructor gets called and deletes the data at _ptr. Then when the program ends and the member gets destroyed, it called the destructor again and tries to delete the already deleted data. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: You need to implement a proper copy constructor and copy assignment operator to at least follow the rule of three

Comment: Side note: `Square(new int)` is enough - you don't need the `Square::`.

Comment: Follow the [rule of three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) and all will be revealed!

Comment: Not what you are asking about but it's not generally a good idea to have a class which must be constructed by passing a heap allocated pointer. Better that the class itself allocates the memory it is managing.

Comment: `member = Square::Square(new int)` constructs a temporary `Square` and then copy/assigns that to `member`.   The temporary and `member` are distinct objects, so both need to be destructed.    Even worse, by default (which is what you get unless you explicitly define an assignment operator), the `_ptr` member of both objects are equal - which means the `new int` is released twice (once by each call of the destructor), causing undefined behaviour.

Comment: And this is why C++ has guidelines, avoid new/deletes in your code whenever you can. Either use a std::unique_ptr<int> (and std::make_unique) or if you want to share ownership of your ptr make it a std::shared_ptr. With unique_ptr you will get all kinds of warnings if you don't manage ownership correctly (as it should). See [C++ core guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines) and lookup anything related to new/delete (and raw pointers)